# CSS arrow filled with a gradient percentage

Tags: css

[image: Arrow]

Hi, I'm scratching my head over this one. I want to create a CSS gradient arrow like the one shown, and with the ability to define the fill of the red section as a percentage. The red block is just a solid colour.

From this [JFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/melon/9FWhg/2/) example I have made some progress on creating the green arrow, but the gradient on the triangle is in the wrong direction. I am still unsure of how to get the red block to fill up as a percentage of the green arrow. For example if the red portion is 90% I'm going to have to somehow create half a triangle. Help please :)

Example Code for the green arrow:

```
div.a3 {
   width: 100px;
   height: 50px;
   position: relative;
   margin: 50px;

   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #99c739 0%,#4eb739 100%);
   background:    -moz-linear-gradient(top, #99c739 0%, #4eb739 100%); 
}

div.a3:after {
   z-index: -1;
   content: "";
   display: block;
   position: absolute;
   right: -75px;
   top: -50px;
   margin: 50px;
   height: 50px;
   width: 50px;

   -webkit-transform:rotate( -45deg );
   -moz-transform:rotate( -45deg );
        transform:rotate( -45deg );

   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(135deg, #99c739 0%, #4eb739 50%, #ffffff 50%, #ffffff 100%);
   background:    -moz-linear-gradient(135deg, #99c739 0%, #4eb739 50%, #ffffff 50%, #ffffff 100%);
}
```

Comment: I'm starting to think perhaps it would be easier to have whole green and red arrow as separate background images in separate divs. Lay the div with the red arrow on top and have the background image 'clipped' by percentage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
div{
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 50px 0;
    position:relative;
    background: #d72200;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,  #d72200 0%, #d72200 20%, #9ac739 20%, #6bbe39 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,#d72200), color-stop(20%,#d72200), color-stop(20%,#9ac739), color-stop(100%,#6bbe39));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  #d72200 0%,#d72200 20%,#9ac739 20%,#6bbe39 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left,  #d72200 0%,#d72200 20%,#9ac739 20%,#6bbe39 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(left,  #d72200 0%,#d72200 20%,#9ac739 20%,#6bbe39 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to right,  #d72200 0%,#d72200 20%,#9ac739 20%,#6bbe39 100%);
}
div:after{
    content:'';
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
    background: #4eb739;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg,  #4eb739 0%, #6bbe39 50%, #6bbe39 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, right top, color-stop(0%,#4eb739), color-stop(50%,#6bbe39), color-stop(100%,#6bbe39));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg,  #4eb739 0%,#6bbe39 50%,#6bbe39 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(45deg,  #4eb739 0%,#6bbe39 50%,#6bbe39 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(45deg,  #4eb739 0%,#6bbe39 50%,#6bbe39 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(45deg,  #4eb739 0%,#6bbe39 50%,#6bbe39 100%);
    -moz-transform: scale(1) rotate(45deg) translate(0px, 0px) skew(0deg, 0deg);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1) rotate(45deg) translate(0px, 0px) skew(0deg, 0deg);
    -o-transform: scale(1) rotate(45deg) translate(0px, 0px) skew(0deg, 0deg);
    -ms-transform: scale(1) rotate(45deg) translate(0px, 0px) skew(0deg, 0deg);
    transform: scale(1) rotate(45deg) translate(0px, 0px) skew(0deg, 0deg);
    z-index: -2;
    margin: 0 0 0 -50px;
}
div:before{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 22px 0;
    z-index: -1;
    background: #fff;
    margin: -22px 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: That's great thanks, but I'm also to hoping to overlay another block on top (the red section) which fills up left to right by a percentage

Comment: I chenged my post. CSS now corresponds to your picture

Answer (score 0):

Below the code seems to create an arrow.

Is it what you are looking for ?

```
    div.a3 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 50px;

    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #1e5799 0%,#2989d8 100%);
    background:    -moz-linear-gradient(left, #1e5799 0%, #2989d8 100%); 
}

div.a3:after {
    z-index: -1;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    right: -75px;
    top: -50px;
    margin: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background: #000;  
            transform:rotate( -45deg );

    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(135deg, #1e5799 0%, #2989d8 50%, #ffffff 50%, #ffffff 100%);
    background:    -moz-linear-gradient(135deg, #1e5799 0%, #2989d8 50%, #ffffff 50%, #ffffff 100%);
}
```

Comment: I need to be able to create the green arrow and the red section on top which can vary in width according to a given percentage.